# Oracle Reports 10g to 11g migration issue

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I am in the middle of a project to transfer and upgrade a legacy, windows server, Oracle Forms and Reports 10g application to a unix server, Oracle Forms and Reports 11g.

We have everything going fine with one exception.  One of our reports is not rendering even close to correct, Data is misaligned or even missing in some instances (it could be trying to print them off the page for all I know).

Comment: The font handling in OAS 11g is greatly different than it was in 10g, and caused us much grief when we went to 11g.  I would start there.  Unfortunately, I don't handle the OAS side of things, so I can't give specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this behaviour before when upgrading from 9i to 10g and when converting from Windows to Linux. The thing to do is open the 10g-windows-created file in the 11g-linux editor, put everything in its right place and then save the file. It should render correctly after that.

It's unfortunate as it's a labour-intensive solution. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if .rdf files aren't intended to be platform- and version-independent.